# Permission Denied Error - SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server, access-control

While executing multple update statements on a particular table simultaneosly, I am getting an error - Permission Denied. Previously, the same was working perfectly. What could be the reason this is getting failed now?

Comment: Your question lacks a bit of information. Can you perhaps post your table structure and your update statements?

Answer (score 0):

Someone tightened up the permissions to one of the tables you are using.